# Flask sustainability for the future

Tags: java, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, flask-socketio

I built a SaaS web application for commercial purpose using Flask as server side framework.

Since a while I'm having worries about Flask and Flask extensions sustainability for the future.

Quoting, among the other on this subject, this Packt article [Open Source Software: Are maintainers the only ones responsible for software sustainability?](https://hub.packtpub.com/open-source-software-are-maintainers-the-only-ones-responsible-for-software-sustainability/):

*The majority of open-source software that the world depends on is built by volunteers. When a business chooses to use open-source software this volunteer labor is essentially an unpaid vendor with no contractual obligations.*

But - unlike the open source volunteers - I do have contractual obligations towards my clients.

So I tried to measure someway the project health by looking at Github numbers and comparing it to other projects, or trying to know how large is the users base for Flask and various extensions (mainly Flask-Sqlalchemy, Flask-Assets, Flask-Login, Flask-Socketio, Flask-WTF, Flask-Mail), , but it's not easy to get a picture. How many active maintainers are there? What is the chance that the project in the near future would lack financial and personnel resources and should quit, and how fast would  this quitting happen?

So I'd like to know if it's generally considered a good practice to include open source frameworks (I mean the ones not supported by big companies) in commercial server-side software for what it concerns future sustainability, and what other people facing with this problem are doing.

Is sometimes porting everything to Java the only safe way to go? (This question is based on the evidence that actually enterprise development is Java. But I also notice that today on Github spring-framework has 429 contributors while flask has got 562. On the other hand spring has 20.141 commits while flask has 3.799).

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the Stack Overflow Developer Survey: 
[Developer Survey](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#technology)

In my expirience, an Open Source framework as big as Flask never died in the past. 
With respect to the article, you provided: not only Open Source projects, even big companies can get something wrong. They often do. Thinking about [WannaCry ransomware attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WannaCry_ransomware_attack) which caused a lot of damage on Windows Systems. And Windows is not an Open Source project.

It is a good thing, to do risk evaluation as you did. In my expirience, you are save using Flask for a commercial project.

Comment: the Developer Survey you suggested is a really significant element for the evaluation I'm trying to do, so thanks. For what it concerns flask being a big project it would be nice to have a way to measure how "big" is big with numbers. I once read that flask has been downloaded more than one hundred milions times, but I really don't know if this can be considered a reasonable number.

Comment: I do not have download numbers for Flask, but here is another useful resource for your evaluation: [Developer Rating](https://www.g2.com/products/flask/reviews)